# What is the point in signing tags in git?

Tags: git

I am quite new in git, and I have seen that it is possible to sign the tags with gpg. I understand how public key cryptography works, and I understand how to do sign the tags, but what is the point in doing it?

Comment: Similar question on cryptography.se: [What are the advantages and disadvantages of cryptographically signing commits and tags in Git?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212192/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-cryptographically-signing-commits-a).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The point of signing a tag is that now anyone who has your public key can prove that you have approved that particular commit as being that particular version of the program. If they happen to trust you as being the official source of releases for that package, then they know that they got an official version of that package, not some random version that might have been backdoored by an attacker or corrupted in transit.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you very much for your answer. So basically it means I can checkout a version from an untrusted source and still make sure the code is unaltered, right? Now if this is useful for tags, why is it not the common procedure for commit and push/pull operations, too?

Comment: @Ken A couple of reasons. For one, it will add friction to the development process, or reduce security. You will either need to constantly be typing your GPG key password, or have an agent loaded which has it stored, which would increase your vulnerability window. Also, people don't necessarily want to commit cryptographically to standing behind patches which are still in the development cycle; maybe they will decide that a patch is a bad idea, and just want to drop that patch, without worrying about someone else assuming it's official due to the signature.

Comment: Also, patches are frequently rebased or otherwise rewritten. When you do that, you would have to drop the original committers signature (since you can't sign with their keys), and maybe add your own, but then it would start to get confusing what each person's signature means (does it mean they wrote the patch? approved it? reviewed it?). By only signing releases, you reduce the confusion; you are just asserting that this tag corresponds to this official version, which has gone through whatever code review and testing process the project has.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could implement signing of each commit yourself using `git notes` and a few helper scripts. And [Monotone](http://www.monotone.ca/), a distributed revision control system that Git was heavily influenced by (the basic representation of commits as chained references to a tree and their parents identified by SHA-1 sums is taken from Monotone) does go the route of signing every commit, so you could check out Monotone if you're interested in this functionality.

Answer (score 13):

Understanding the basics of the [git object model](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html) shows the value of signing tags.

The diagram below, borrowed from the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html), depicts a particular snapshot. The shaded boxes are git objects. The commit object at left refers to a tree. Think of a tree like a filesystem directory, so a tree object refers to other trees and blobs. A blob object stores file contents.

[image: git objects]

Every git object has a SHA1, a unique 40-character hex digest derived from that object's contents. The abbreviated hex strings above the objects represent their respective SHA1s.

Git objects are immutable: changing *even a single bit* of the object's contents changes its name. It's SHA1s all the way down. Any change to a blob requires a new tree and then in turn a new commit, so it's impossible to both slip in different contents and [avoid detection](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html). Knowing only the SHA1 of a commit gives you a precise, integrity-checked snapshot of a tree.

A commit also refers to its immediate parent (or multiple parents in the case of merges), so the guarantee is even stronger. Changing a single bit *anywhere in a commit's history* also changes its SHA1. Knowing only a single commit's SHA1 gives you a huge amount of information: an exact tree in the context of an exact history going all the way back to the first commit.

Anyone can create commits, and anyone can *claim* to be, say, Linus Torvalds. It's important to know which commits are trustworthy. A signed tag that refers to a commit gives you all of the above information along with verifiable authenticity. Many projects use signed tags as a way of stamping Officially Blessed Releases.

Comment: Does anyone know what software was used to create the excellent diagrams in the Git Community Book?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'd like to know too. Maybe it deserves its own Stack Overflow question!

Comment: done: http://superuser.com/questions/286263/what-software-was-used-to-create-the-diagrams-in-the-git-community-book

Comment: exactly, but being that said why do you need to sign even. Because the commit hash will say it all, whether its trustworthy or not. If the SHA-1s are equal, its trustworthy. Anyway you need to have the public key of the owner to verify, why not just have the SHA-1 and verify. why a whole new concept ?