# Retroactively sign git commits

Tags: git, security, version-control, commit, gnupg

Recent versions of git (>= 1.7.9) support signing individual commits with GPG.

Is it possible to retroactively sign all commits within a tree?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to gpg sign all previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882919/is-there-a-way-to-gpg-sign-all-previous-commits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> retroactively sign all commits within a tree?

Yes: add a [tag, that you would sign](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html#signed_tags).
That is actually the [preferred option](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149199/why-do-some-open-source-projects-do-not-accept-pull-requests-but-emailing-patch/149202#149202) when it comes to sign commits: sign a all set of them through a tag, rather than signing each one individually.
See "[How to get pusher's Information in post-receive hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280900/6309)".

---

Note (update may 2017) that only Git 2.13.x/2.14 (Q3 2017) will completely fix the signing process, because "`git cherry-pick`" and other uses of the sequencer machinery and mishandled a trailer block whose last line is an incomplete line.
This has been fixed so that an additional sign-off etc. are added *after* completing the existing incomplete line.

See [commit 44dc738](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44dc738a39f2c4dba41c0ddacae280d0f88dc71f) (26 Apr 2017) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6ebfa10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ebfa10439e50175f24874b39c16fea6560adefe), 16 May 2017)</sup>

> ### `sequencer`: add newline before adding footers

> When encountering a commit message that does not end in a newline,
> sequencer does not complete the line before determining if a blank line
> should be added.
> This causes the "`(cherry picked...`" and sign-off lines to **sometimes appear on the same line as the last line of the commit message**.
>
> This behavior was introduced by [commit 967dfd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/967dfd4d568c2b102281de8cc22ee35f7558358b) ("sequencer: use
> trailer's trailer layout", 2016-11-29). However, a revert of that commit
> would not resolve this issue completely: prior to that commit, a
> conforming footer was deemed to be non-conforming by
> `has_conforming_footer()` if there was no terminating newline, resulting
> in both conforming and non-conforming footers being treated the same
> when they should not be.
>
> Resolve this issue, both for conforming and non-conforming footers, and in both `do_pick_commit()` and `append_signoff()`, by **always adding a
> newline to the commit message if it does not end in one before checking
> the footer for conformity**.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), this will be more reliable.

See [commit 842385b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/842385b8a4fa56678f13cda599ee96463004e7bf), [commit 9dad073](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dad073d4b9b6679c3e86f28aacf79f85ed786d2), [commit 26e28fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26e28fe7bbdf8b22ed096dfd76a9311e86ffb200), [commit 75d3bee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75d3bee15778a3aaeb8234023fc224838ac53181), [commit 20f4b04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20f4b044a681fffd469cc9ddcf055580a20fd612), [commit 5b9427e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b9427e0ac4d4b6c96f23fc5eb9b047a27563c65), [commit 8d2aa8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d2aa8dfac4048c964453a8983f1dc12ecdfe1c3), [commit 424e28f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/424e28fcadfe0a40e444687c10fb4eaff8360f8d), [commit e885a84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e885a84f1bc660adfc1dea5f6c25d0a92c7c9dbc), [commit 185e865](https://github.com/git/git/commit/185e86522678fed077d6cec02381bcf899bf24e5) (30 Sep 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 19dd352](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19dd352d03adc75d0b6530975a44b7bb23c69063), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dad073d4b9b6679c3e86f28aacf79f85ed786d2): handle `ignore_footer` when parsing trailers
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The `append_signoff()` function takes an `"ignore_footer"` argument, which specifies a number of bytes at the end of the message buffer which should not be considered (they cannot contain trailers, and the trailer is spliced in before them).
>
> But to find the existing trailers, it calls into `has_conforming_trailer()`. That function takes an `ignore_footer` parameter, but since [967dfd4d56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/967dfd4d568c2b102281de8cc22ee35f7558358b) ("`sequencer`: use trailer's trailer layout", 2016-11-02, Git v2.12.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b0db484e11aa86e6b8bf4d7243d0c81bf4b3c33) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6610af872f6494a061780ec738c8713a034b848b)) the parameter is completely ignored.
>
> The trailer interface we're using takes a single string, with no option to tell it to use part of the string. However, since we have a mutable `strbuf`, we can work around this by simply overwriting (and later restoring) the boundary with a `NUL`.
>
> I'm not sure if this can actually trigger a bug in practice. It's easy to get a non-zero `ignore_footer` by doing something like this:
>
> ```
> git commit -F - --cleanup=verbatim <<-EOF
> subject  
>
> body  
>
> Signed-off-by: me  
>
> # this looks like a comment, but is actually in the
> # message! That makes the earlier s-o-b fake.
> EOF  
>
> git commit --amend -s
> ```
>
> There git-commit calls `ignore_non_trailer()` to count up the "#" cruft, which becomes the `ignore_footer` header. But it works even without this patch! That's because the trailer code *also* calls `ignore_non_trailer()` and skips the cruft, too. So it happens to work because the only callers with a non-zero `ignore_footer` are using the exact same function that the trailer parser uses internally.
>
> And that seems true for all of the current callers, but there's nothing guaranteeing it. We're better off only feeding the correct buffer to the trailer code in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I've been using signed tags for quite a while now. The discussion from Linus helped put it in context.

Comment: Signing just a tag is no guarantee of the validity of all the commits that came before it. Things get missed. Don't take security tips from Linus Torvalds. The guy is an absolute genius, don't get me wrong, but he's historically a headache for security specialists. :)

Comment: @DanielM - Its not clear to me what problem [commit signing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39708082) solves. I think its a solution looking for a problem. I'm fairly certain its a spin on the well known problem of ***[Authentication is not Authorization](https://threatpost.com/javas-losing-security-legacy/102176/)***. But in Git's instance the spin is ***Authentication is not Code Integrity***.

Comment: What does using https solve? It's a near effortless step (when you don't muck it up like I did) that guarantees that the author is the author in the same way https proves the server is the server it says it is. I have had a colleague mark a commit as authored by me. He did it with the best of intentions, and in front of me, and all my actually commits were signed, but it underlines that people can do it without the best intentions. For a new project I'm setting up I'm going to make the CI reject unsigned commits or unrecognised signatures for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 4):

The signature from `git commit`'s `--gpg-sign` (aka `-S`) option is part of the data that is used to generate the sha1 hash that identifies the commit. So retroactively signing commits would require changing the ID of every commit to which that was done.

If you really want to you could probably do something with `git filter-branch`, but it would be better to just sign new commits. Since the commit ID of all ancestors will influence the data that would be signed by any new commit this will still allow gpg verification of the old commits by way of the new, signed commits.

Comment: Thanks. So: possible, but destructive. And signed tags provide most of the advantages already.

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a new branch from the point where you want to start signing your commits. I recently did that for a branch that I created on a machine without access to my private key:

```
# git checkout -b new-branch <last-signed-commit>
# git cherry-pick <first-unsigned-commit>
# git checkout unsigned-branch
# git rebase new-branch
```

This requires that your Git is configured to automatically sign your commits, and there obviously shouldn’t be too many merge commits, other the rebase will look weird. If in doubt, cherry-pick your commits; each picked commit will then be signed.