# Resign previous Git commits with a new GPG key

Tags: git, security, digital-signature, git-commit, gnupg

I am trying to transition to a new GPG key. I would like to re-sign all of my previous commits in a Git repository (that have a *valid signature with my formerly used key*) with the new GPG key.

In other words, how can I automatically resign (with my new key) all of the commits that I signed with my previous key?

If you need key fingerprints to use in your example, please use `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` as my old GPG key fingerprint and `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111` as my new key fingerprint.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) (as [done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31640257/6309)), at least:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@"' HEAD
```

(Probably with a more complex directive, as [seen here](https://superuser.com/a/1509840/141), if you want to sign only your commits)

The new [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) does not support yet GPG signing ([issue 67](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/67)).

Another approach, also [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60790829/6309), is by using `git rebase`:

```
git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -S<keyid>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit? How would I resign all of the commits on the `main` branch?