# What problem or threat does commit signing solve?

Tags: git, git-commit, sign

We use GitHub and we have a request to [perform commit signing](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/290). After studying the process, it's not clear to me what problem commit signing solves. As I understand the process, there's *"local source code"* that gets committed to a *"local repo"* that gets pushed to a *"remote repo"*. So there are three boxes, and two arrows creating a directed graph from the local source files to the remote repository. For the end user, the flows are reversed.

In the model as described, it seems like we want the authorizations to occur at the push to the remote repo; and commit signings have nearly no benefit.

The Git SCM manual, [7.4 Git Tools - Signing Your Work](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) does not state the problem it is solving. It does tell me to hunt for the answer, however:

> ***Everyone Must Sign***
>
> Signing tags and commits is great, but if you decide to use this in
>   your normal workflow, you’ll have to make sure that everyone on your
>   team understands how to do so. If you don’t, you’ll end up spending a
>   lot of time helping people figure out how to rewrite their commits
>   with signed versions. Make sure you understand GPG and the benefits of
>   signing things before adopting this as part of your standard workflow.

I'm presuming the Git engineers have modeled the Git workflows. They identified a problem (or problems), and they placed the *"commit signing"* security control to remediate it. I'd like to know what problems they identified and solved with *"commit signing"*.

I think what has happened is folks are confusing/conflating [Authentication with Authorization](http://threatpost.com/javas-losing-security-legacy/102176/) or maybe Code Integrity. Unfortunately, Authentication ***is not*** Authorization or Code Integrity despite the willingness to make it so.

What problem does git commit signing solve?

Comment: "He mostly came to the same conclusion." What conclusion is that?

Comment: Signing allows to verify that object came from specific person (owner of private key) and was not modified since then.

Comment: Commit signing is used to verify the identity of the person who made the commit. I probably don't quite understand the question because the second and third paragraphs seem completely non-sequitur.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - the information from the email was added to the question.

Comment: @JJJ - *"Commit signing is used to verify the identity of the person who made the commit"* - How does it do that? Its easy to forge all that information and get a user to accept it as authentic. I'm not sure how the second and third paragraphs are irrelevant. The second describes the model. The third is a cross-check with someone who specializes in the field.

Comment: If you can verify the signatures, it is important because you can verify that it wasn't *me* that said "I broke it" on his behalf.

Comment: The signature is cryptographically secure. You can't forge it without access to the original private key.

Comment: @jww then come up with a better title, and don't circumvent the list of restricted words by intentionally misspelling them.

Comment: He can create a GPG key using your name and email address, but such a key would not match the public key that should have been previously disseminated, either with the repository itself or through some other means.

Comment: @jww That isn't how GPG keys work. Anybody can create a key on your behalf, but nobody else would trust that it is actually your key. After the fact, when you're repairing the damage done by the intruder, you would be able to look at all of the commits and easily identify the ones signed with the wrong key. Signed commits aren't about keeping people from breaking into the central repository of your repo, they have **nothing to do with that**. They're about being *cryptographically certain* about who the author of a commit is.

Comment: @jww There is no semantic difference in our titles. Please stop harping on the word "problem", it adds nothing to your question.

Comment: @jww You're not listening to the answers anybody here is giving you, there is nothing theoretical about this. You are the one who suggested the break-in scenario, so without commit signing, how will you fix your repo if somebody breaks into it and rewrites history to introduce a bunch of commits signed with your name?

Comment: Commit signing solves the practical problem of verifying the author of the commit, or at least making it significantly harder to impersonate someone else. That is all. Whether or not you think that's a problem that needs to be solved in your project is a discussion you should have with the project participants at Github, not here.

Comment: @jww The paragraph you are repeatedly reintroducing does not belong in your question. Your question already contains the sentence "What problem does git commit signing solve?" and there is no semantic difference between our two titles, nor any reason to stuff a leading blob of redundant meta information into the question. Stop rolling back my changes, please.

Comment: I feel like the impetus to this question is a little unclear.  You could ask what problem this is attempting to address, which is a very broad thing indeed, or you could frame it in the scope of what problem this project perceives there is such that signed commits are a solution.  What I'm asking is, could you describe the actual problem here, rather than your opinion on the solution, and frame it in the context of the solution?

Comment: @meagar - I added additional information. Please ensure it improves the question. Its a genuine effort; and not flippant. And thank for taking the time in the past. It was rude not to thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 38):

The problem that commit signing solves is the same problem that digitally signing a document solves: the problem of verifying its author.

Since only the author has their private key, only they can sign the commit as themselves.

If I trust an particular comitter and they have signed their commit, I can trust their code without necessarily hand-verifying every line.

---

Consider the case where someone forked your repository on github and then added a bunch of commits which introduced security vulnerabilities to your code. They made these commits with the tuple `author name, author email, commit name, commit email` set to one of the original authors.

Without commit signing, there is no way to verify that they are not the original author.

With commit signing, these forged commits cannot be signed because the forger does not have the author's private key.

Comment: Similarly, signing tags (esp. while cutting a release) is a *verifiable* indication that the point was marked by someone that people trust so that they can be sure that the release is approved.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, Thanks for adding that as a comment. I didn't mention this originally since the OP asked about signing commits specifically, but it is an equally valid use of signatures in git.

Comment: You're welcome. I often use this an example while training to show the difference between the author of commit "v1.1" and the creator of the tag "v1.1" and whose fault is it if the build broke there.

Comment: Thanks merlin. So, at minimum, commit signing can be used to establish some provenance, but that's dependent on the key distribution problem and user action. And it does not address address user confidence scams, like phishing. Is that correct?

Comment: @jww, That is an accurate summary, yes. Since your library contains crypto tools, it may also make the cryptographers who are using your tools feel more comfortable since they at least _have the opportunity to verify_ authorship of commits.

Comment: @merlin2011 - You know, after the protracted debate in the bug report and hours wasted trying to figure out the actual problem *commit signing* solves... `git merge -Sm "..."` is broken and produces the error message `not something we can merge git merge integer failed`. And `git log` does not even show the damn commit was signed. This tool is so defective by design.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of git?

Comment: "If I trust an particular comitter and they have signed their commit, I can trust their code without necessarily hand-verifying every line." -- GPG signing doesn't remove the need of code review :) Actually, I'd say, that you can just trust, that it's really THAT committer committed code, not someone else.