# Lost GPG Key for Git

Tags: github, gnupg

I lost my GPG Key for GitHub and was wondering what I should do. Should I keep and create a new one or revoke it? Will revoking the key on my account cause my commits to be unverified?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can [generate a new one](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/).

Revoking the old one means old [commits signed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20628543/6309) with the old gpgp keys won't be [verifiable anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24090258/6309). You can [add new (signed) tags to old commits though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13507498/6309).