# Get the repo name from which commits are being pushed to central repo in post-receive script

Tags: git

I am trying to print the `repo name` from which the `commits are being pushed on to the central repo` in the `post-receive script` that is used for mailing git pushes .
I tried adding the following code to a script from

https://github.com/zma/usefulscripts/blob/master/script/post-receive

IN main -

```
        dir=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
        echo "$dir"
        base=`basename "$dir"`
        echo "$base"
```

But it prints nothing when I do a push.
can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to get the repository name of your local repository on the server when you push? I don't think that's possible. May I ask why?

Comment: So that I can display it in the email from which repo the push is being done

Comment: Relevant: [How to get pusher's Information in post-receive hooks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280661/how-to-get-pushers-information-in-post-receive-hooks)