# Why sign Git tags?

Tags: git, security, gnupg, git-tag

Git provides the option to sign annotated tags with your GPG private key, but what is wrong with just accepting a tag's claimed origin? What damage could a spoofed tag do when the tag does not alter the commit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the point in signing tags in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663733/what-is-the-point-in-signing-tags-in-git)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is wrong with just accepting a tag's claimed origin?

That you have no guarantee that it's correct, you'd have to put trust in every single person who has access to the repo (authorized or not) not to falsely create a tag. Signing guarantees (at least as much as GPG can offer) that the person who created the tag is who you think they are.

> What damage could a spoofed tag do when the tag does not alter the commit?

None. You seem to have gotten two different ideas confused here. A tag and a commit are completely separate objects—a tag *points to* a commit, but a tag is not a commit. Thus, a tag will never alter a commit. This is potentially where more danger lies: a falsified tag will not change the commit history unexpectedly, and would more easily go unnoticed.

Comment: I think the interesting point is actually more along the lines of: Since commits aren't signed, what's the point of signing a tag?  We can verify that the tagger is who they are, but we can't verify the committer, so what's the point?

Comment: @stacy You seem to be trying to claim we shouldn't be able to sign tags because we can't sign commits—which doesn't make much sense. Why remove a feature just because it doesn't exist elsewhere. Regardless, the assumption is that the tag signed is a person of authority who has reviewed the state of the code at that commit and vouches for its soundness.

Comment: @slacy, even more to the point, the signed tag points to a specific immutable version of the codebase.  The commit isn't signed, but the commit hash itself is cryptographically secure.  If you wrote down the 40 hex digits of the commit hash or could remember them perfectly, you would never need a tag (signed or unsigned).