# How to verify integrity of git repo

Tags: git, security, github

I recently learned that git links users to commits based on the user.email in git config.

https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

This raises questions about what to do in the case of a key leakage. If I learned that an attacker had short term access to my repo what would be the best way to go about verifying no one has modified the repo contents? Review the code? Look at the shas?

Comment: What to you mean by "verifying"?

Comment: I edited the question. Specifically wondering how to see if the history has been modified or if code was injected in. It just seems like a potential security problem for a project and I am not sure how to deal with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sign tags:

See: [Signing tags in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663733/signing-tags-in-git)

That way, at least up to a tag, you know your code has not been tampered.

Now, if you want to verify that no unauthorised code got in. You can set up a second, trusted repository and only merge in commits that you have reviewed.