# Why does Git use confusingly similar names like "origin foo", "remotes/origin/foo", and "origin/foo"?

Tags: git, git-fork

I've been asked to use the Fork Workflow, namely that I have to deal with multiple branches that have the same or similar name. Why should I use these different variations?

Here are some examples of the different naming conventions:

- mybranch
- origin mybranch
- origin/mybranch
- remotes/origin/mybranch
- upstream mybranch
- upstream/mybranch

Comment: git doesn't use names with spaces by default, can you show the context in which these names originated? I suspect they are 2 distinct words, for instance specifying two distinct parameters to a command. For instance, `origin/mybranch` is "the local tracking branch that tracks the branch mybranch on the remote named origin". However, "origin mybranch" might mean "the remote named origin and the branch named mybranch", but these might be two distinct parameters. Also note that the two things I just described *are not the same*.

Comment: Yes they are 2 distinct words e.g. git push origin foo, but origin I assume is a qualifier that says where foo is.

Comment: Yes, the name of the remote, but "names of remotes" appear in the naming of branches as well.

Comment: Can you explain that?

Comment: I am not sure I can. By that I mean, I'm not sure *I* am qualified to explain everything, and to be honest, this whole question seems to be more suited for a discussion somewhere than a "here's my question and this is the answer to it" type of site, since I really don't know how deep your knowledge or confusion goes.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, let me post a few comments and see if we can clear up *some* of the confusion.

Comment: Let's assume I go to github, create a new repository, and check the checkbox for initializing the repository with a README file. This will add 1 commit with that file, and as part of that set up the `master` branch, on github, to point to that commit. I then clone this repository locally using something like `git clone https://github.com/lassevk/dummy-repo.git dummy`, to get a local "dummy" folder with my local clone.

Comment: If I now, inside this folder, execute `git branch -a`, I will see 3 branches being listed. `master`, `remotes/origin/HEAD` (but let's ignore this one), and `remotes/origin/master`. The first branch is a **local** branch, and was created for me, and checked out. It is tracking the github branch, which is also named `master`, by setting up a tracking relationship to that third branch, `remotes/origin/master`.

Comment: It doesn't. It uses intentionally related names for related things.

Comment: This third branch, `remotes/origin/master`, often just shortened down to `origin/master` is a branch that lives in my local repository but mirrors the position/state of the `master` branch on the remote `origin` *the last time we talked to that remote*, which was the clone.

Comment: So in essence, we now have 3 branches. We have the master branch, on github, we have the local master branch, and we have a local tracking branch named `remotes/origin/master` (again, usually shortened down to `origin/master`) that tracks the master branch on github.

Comment: If you want to refer to any of those 3 branches, you need to use their respective names. Git commands, executed locally, can refer to the two local branches by using their names, `master` and `origin/master`, but in order to refer to the master branch **on github** you usually have to use a command that **talks to the remote**. This is where those names are split up. For instance, if you want to delete the master branch **on github**, you can execute `git push origin -d master`, here the names are split up.

Comment: However, if you want to delete the local tracking branch `origin/master`, you need to use its name, and execute `git branch -d origin/master`. (btw, this is not a good idea unless something has *already* gone wrong, so don't do it)

Comment: Since you also mention "upstream", this is just the name of another remote, like origin is, for instance you might want to push to both bitbucket and github, you would then set up two distinct remotes for those. "upstream", however, is a naming convention for the "source of your fork" *usually*. It doesn't have to be, the name "upstream" means nothing to git, just as "origin" doesn't, except that you have configuration locally that points to bitbucket, github, etc. You could've named them "github" or "ThatDangRemote" for all git cares.

Comment: Re-reading my comments I can see several mistakes I've made, so as I said, I'm not sure *I* am qualified to provide an *answer* to this. They're not that important though, so they shouldn't mean much in the context of this question.

Comment: So a branch that is local is prefixed with remotes... why? I don't understand why it is that one set of rational rules exist in programming for naming parts of code, which are totally ignored in the context of GIT. Names are supposed to be appropriate and to have the expected meaning. In the context of GIT, it's an upside-down world, where a local thing is called remote.

Comment: So those 6 "names" you listed mean this: The local branch `mybranch`, (probably) the branch `mybranch` on the remote named origin, the local tracking branch for the former, the same as the previous (`remotes/` is usually omitted, optional), and then two branches that uses the origin named "upstream" instead of "origin" but otherwise means the same as 2 and 3.

Comment: No, the **full** name to branches are `refs/heads/<local branch>`, `refs/remotes/<tracking branch>`, but `refs/` and `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` are allowed to be omitted, as long as the rest of the name is unique. So "local branches", **not** to be confused with "local tracking branches" is prefixed with `refs/heads` whereas "local tracking branches" is prefixed with `refs/remotes/".

Comment: How did GIT become so popular if it is this confusing? I don't recall any problem like this with SVN. Surely it wasn't the "star power" of Linus Torvalds that led to GIT being adopted?

Comment: There's information stored locally about branches that exists on the remote, this information is attached to names in the same global namespace as local branches. Local branches lives in `/refs/heads/`, metadata about remote branches lives in `/refs/remotes/`.

Comment: As with all things GIT related, no one has a full understanding. All I want is a clear set of commands to use to get my work done. Honestly I don't have this.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful reciting a series of memorized Git commands. Git has a [simple but powerful object model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664386/123109). Learn how git commands work in terms of the object model and how what you want to do fits what the commands do. In my experience, running memorized commands sometimes leads to several repeated invocations in frustration of the same sequence, which can tangle the history in bizarre ways. After the puzzled teammate comes to ask for help, I sit down, look at the current status, scratch my head, and ask “How’d you get in *this* state?”

The naming scheme for tracking branches (*e.g.*, `origin/mybranch` or `remotes/origin/mybranch` — or even `refs/remotes/origin/mybranch` and likewise for `upstream/mybranch`) leaks an implementation detail for branch namespaces, *viz.* that `refs`, `remotes,` and `origin` are physical directories when stored unpacked. See the [`git pack-refs` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) or go spelunking in the directory hierarchy beneath `.git/refs`.

Git accepts abbreviated names of branches for user convenience, similar to how users need not type the entire 40-character SHA1 object name. The [`git rev-parse` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem) explains.

> **`<refname>`, e.g. `master`, `heads/master`, `refs/heads/master`**
>   A symbolic ref name. E.g. `master` typically means the commit object
>   referenced by `refs/heads/master`. If you happen to have both
>   `heads/master` and `tags/master`, you can explicitly say `heads/master` to tell Git which one you mean. When ambiguous, a `<refname>` is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

The Git documentation refers to `refs/remotes/origin/foo` as a *symbolic full name* or *full refname*, and they are useful for specifying an precise reference by name with no possibility for ambiguity — such as in an automated program.

Note that `mybranch` refers to your *local* `mybranch`, as opposed to its tracking branch (or remote-tracking branch) `origin/mybranch` or `upstream/mybranch`. Tracking branches are updated with each fetch or pull. Think of them as bookmarks in your history or road signs along the path for where the remote had that branch the last time you pulled. It is possible for — and happens frequently that — `mybranch` and `origin/mybranch` refer to different commits.

In contrast `origin mybranch` never refers to `origin/mybranch` or `mybranch`. Git does not have a “`/` operator.” This thinking lifts these *two separate arguments* out of context. Remember that Git is a suite of command line tools, command line tools accept arguments as positional parameters, and Unix command shells split arguments by whitespace. In context, the command

```
git push origin master
```

has general form

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

That is, one of the arguments names a remote and the other names a (usually local) branch. So in English, it means “Push the commits on my `<branch>` (named `master` in this case) to a remote (named `origin` in this case).”

Answer (score 3):

The reason this stuff is confusing is that Git was not written all at once.  Git was written over the course of many years (it's now approaching two decades).  Some mistakes were made early on; some things were not very convenient; and Git maintains backwards compatibility with usage going back to 2005, if not earlier.

What you need to know is that Git, today, has:

- *Remotes*.  A *remote* is a simple short name like `origin` or `upstream`.  A remote has a couple of functions.  The most important one is that it lets you avoid retyping a URL over and over again.

  When you run `git clone`, you get one remote automatically.  The name of this remote defaults to `origin` (you can change it, but there's no real reason to do that).  So almost every Git repository has an `origin`, because most people make Git repositories by cloning.
- "Fork" is just a web-hosting-service variant of "clone" with added features.  You usually have to make your own *additional* clone, after you make a fork on a web-hosting service.  Thus, after you make a fork, there are now *three* separate Git repositories:

  - The one you forked on the web hosting service.  You don't control this one at all.
  - Your fork on the web hosting service.  The hosting service actually control this Git repository, but they give you web pages and URLs to delegate control to you.
  - Your clone on your own computer.  This clone has a URL, saved under the name `origin`, that you can use to control your fork on the web hosting service.

  In order to deal with all three repositories, you'll create *another* of these "remote" things in your clone.  You already have the one named `origin`, so you created a second one, which you called `upstream`, which holds a URL for the *other* one on the web hosting service.  This one is read-only to you—you're only going to use it to *get* stuff *from* the original repository (the one you forked).
- *Remote-tracking names*.  Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names* but putting the word *branch* in here is, I think, just confusing.  It's too temping to say *remote-tracking branch* without the word *name* and then it gets *really* confusing, so leave out the word *branch* entirely and just call them *remote-tracking names*.

#### A little bit of history

Original Git—the one that started to get popular, perhaps because of Linux and/or Linus—did not have *remotes* or *remote-tracking names* at all.  People just typed the URLs over and over.  You would run:

```
git pull <url> <branch>
```

and everything was pretty clear and obvious: you were telling your own Git: *Hey Git, go call up another Git at the URL I just gave you, and get commits from their branch that I named here on the command line.*

That's full of opportunities for mistakes and typos.  In particular, who wants to keep typing in `http://some.web.host/some/long/path/to/repo.git` over and over?  So there were numerous attempts at giving you a short and easy-to-type way of not re-entering the URL every time.  The one that caught on was the *remote*:

```
git remote add origin http://some.web.host/some/long/path/to/repo.git
```

Now you can type `origin` instead of the long URL.  Moreover, because you probably typed in the URL once to do `git clone`, `git clone` *itself* can create `origin` *for* you.  There won't be any typos or mistakes any more.  Obviously, this is better.

Meanwhile ... why should you have to type in the *branch name* too?  Suppose you keep doing this, over and over:

```
git checkout dev
...
git pull origin dev
...
git push origin dev
...
git pull origin dev
...
git push origin dev
```

Wouldn't it be nice not to have to type in `origin dev` every time?  Well, that too got added to Git.  Git can, now, remember one *upstream* for each branch.  ***This upstream is not the same as your `upstream` remote.***  That one is your fault :-) although no doubt you just followed some tutorial example.  The tutorials all called the second remote "upstream", without thinking about the fact that branches also have an *upstream*, so now it's traditional to use the literal string `upstream` for the *second* remote that you need because of forks.

Meanwhile, *forks* weren't even a thing, back in the day.  They became popular because of GitHub and Bitbucket and other web-hosting services.  Fork still isn't a *Git* thing: it's something the web-hosting services provide.  As far as Git is concerned, all Git repositories are just Git repositories.  There's no worrying about whether something is a "fork", it's just a Git repository.

Given that you have a *remote* named `origin`, and that's a Git repository, it might be nice if *your* Git repository could call them up, find out all their branches (and corresponding commits), and remember them for you.  Your Git *does* do that.  That's what these *remote-tracking names* are all about.

Suppose you have a branch named `dev`, and you send it to `origin` and get it from `origin` all the time.  The other Git, over on the web hosting service whose URL is kept under your name `origin`, *also* calls *its* branch `dev`.  Whenever your Git calls up their Git, your Git can see *their* `dev`.  Your Git copies their `dev` to your *remote-tracking name*, which is `origin/dev`.  Your remote-tracking names are your Git's way of remembering: *this is what their branch was, the last time I talked to them.*

Last, the *upstream of a branch* is generally going to be the *remote-tracking name* that you are using.  That is, we just noted that you keep sending your commits to `origin`'s `dev`, and getting commits from `origin`'s `dev` to put into your `dev`.  So you'll tell your own Git: *set the upstream for my `dev` to be my `origin/dev`.*  That neatly—but confusingly—ties your `dev` to both `origin` *and* its `dev` (which you remember as your `origin/dev`).

But `git pull` has to be compatible with 2005 or before.  Back then, there *was* no `origin`; there *was* no `origin/dev`; you had to type in:

```
git pull <big-long-url> dev
```

Using:

```
git pull origin dev
```

*is* backwards-compatible with 2005-or-before: Git just translates `origin` to the URL.  You use `origin dev` here—instead of `origin/dev`—because you're providing two separate things: the URL to their Git, and the branch name their Git uses.

Whenever you work *locally*—which is most of the time, in Git—you use `origin/dev`: your Git's memory of their Git's `dev`.  But when you use `git push`, you're not working locally: you are having your Git dial another Git over the Internet, via a URL.  So here go you back to using a separate branch name.